# Linux sound - Can't activate sound in linux

Tags: sound

I can't use any driver for sound. It is always mute.
The sound setting has no device for input or output.

[image]
`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`

```
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [1043:8534]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05)
--
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1043:8576]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
W: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to open configuration file '/home/uidn0919/.config/pulse//daemon.conf': Permission denied
W: [pulseaudio] daemon-conf.c: Failed to open configuration file: Permission denied
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audio [Plantronics Wireless Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pactl list short sinks`

```
W: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to open configuration file '/home/user/.config/pulse//daemon.conf': Permission denied
W: [pulseaudio] daemon-conf.c: Failed to open configuration file: Permission denied
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Edit:

```
$ find ~/.pulse ~/.config ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls
find: ‘/home/user/.pulse’: No such file or directory
  3675263      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 user andrei         23 iul 11 17:45 /home/user/.config/pulse/e21eaad1df844214a04f0d2ed372765e-runtime -> /tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n
$ sudo chown -R "$USER:" ~/.pulse ~/.config
chown: cannot access '/home/user/.pulse': No such file or directory*
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Thanks.

Comment: Weird that `~/.config/pulse` isn't accessible. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `find ~/.pulse ~/.config ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls`? If it produces *any output at all*, please run `sudo chown -R "$USER:" ~/.pulse ~/.config` and try again. If the output is empty, reboot log out and back in (or reboot). Now, if sound still doesn't work, please rerun the last two commands of my previous comment and update your question. Thanks.

Comment: What Linux is this? Is it Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes it is Ubunt 16.04